# Preserve Data-structure on AJAX postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-structures, partial-postback

```
    Partial Class ClientCenter_UpdateSub
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Structure PInfo
        Dim Name As String
        Dim Surname As String
    End Structure

    Dim OldPInfo As New PInfo

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not IsPostBack Then
          'blah blah
           OldPInfo.Name = Dt.Rows(0).Item("Name").ToString
           OldPInfo.Surname = Dt.Rows(0).Item("Surname").ToString
end if        
end sub
    End Class
```

The first time the page loads my structrure is filled correctly. 
After an AJAX postback all the structure fields are setting to nothing. (It seems that the `Dim OldPInfo As New PInfo` is called again), but i should better ask the SO Experts.

So anyway, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, You should never assign a variable outside of a property or a method.

Second, web applications are stateless (which means NOTHING is automatically saved from call to call - unless you store it somewhere like Viewstate, Session, etc.).

---

Remember to accept this answer if it helps solve your problem.